# не могу присвоить текст из html в переменную Selenium Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, xpath

Есть код страницы:
[image: Код страницы]

```
br>

div class="collapse" id="collapse_1409943">_ /div>

"ДО1 №0017687 от 09.03.2020" == $0

br>
```

В нем есть текст `"ДО1 №0017687 от 09.03.2020"`

Но я так понимаю, он не является элементом, так как когда пытаюсь его выцепить такой командой

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[2]').text

print(el)
```

Пайтон пишет вот такую ошибку  `is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`

Но никак не могу найти команды или решения, что бы этот текст присвоить своей переменной.

Comment: Попробуйте текст написать в div

Comment: `text()[2]` а как это работает? Вот это понятно `/td[2]/text()` берем текст второго td, а вот с `text()[2]` вопросы :) А так, попробуйте именно элемент вытаскивать, а не текст: `el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]').text`

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понял. 
Я беру ссылку полного пути Xpath из браузера
/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[2]
и вставляю уже ее.
Плюс если убрать метод .text
И запустить код 
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[2]')

print(el)
То он тоже ругается:
[object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: @Robert, проверяли с моим xpath?

Comment: @gil9red, Магия. спасибо. Вот только он вытащил мне вообще весь текст из блока. Но большое спасибо. С этим можно уже работать!

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает `[object Text]. It should be an element.` из-за того, что нужно возвращать элемент, т.е. `тег`, а по `'/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[2]'` вернется текст тега, поэтому решением может быть:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]').text
```

Но можно пойти дальше и попробовать вытащить текст из блока (считаем что блок из скриншота в вопросе находится внутри того `td[2]`):

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]//div[@class="collapse"]').text
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='collapse']").text
 Здесь("//div[@class='collapse']") мы указываем что относительно div с классом 'collapse' мы вытаскиваем текст.
Если вытащится еще какой-то текст, разбейте его на элементы и присвойте переменной те(по счету), который вам нужны:
el = el.split()[0:3]